# Match a possibly negative number that may or may not be double

Tags: java, regex

I am building a temperature converter in Java. The user will input a number into a `JTextField`, pick their starting label using a `JComboBox`, and pick their ending label using `JRadioButton`s in a `ButtonGroup`. The number that the user enters can be of varying possiblities. It can be

- A single integer, such as **5**
- A multiple integer, such as **55**
- A double, such as **5.5**
- A negative version of any of the above, such as **-5**, **-55**, or **-5.5**

The `JTextField` has a method `getText()`, which returns the value of the string. This is then converted to a double, and finally converted to the desired ending label. Because the String has to be converted to a double, alpha characters can't be allowed in the `JTextField`. So I am using regex to solve this. I currently have

```
String tempV = startTempValInput.getText();
if (tempV.matches("-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")) {
   // Code Here
}
```

However, this doesn't recognize single or multiple integers. How can I modify this to include integers?

Comment: Can the user ask: 'What is `.5` degree's C ?'

Comment: @sln Yes, it would just have to be asked as `0.5` degrees

Comment: if you just plan on validating a string that won't bounce on a string to double method `.5` is allowed and valid. If interested I posted a regex that should validate all such numeric string representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempV.matches("-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?")
```

Breaking it down:

- `-?` - This will match a negative number 0 or 1 time
- `[0-9]+` - This will match a numeric character 1 or more times
- `(\\.[0-9]+)?` - This will match a possible decimal place to infinity

  - `\\.` - This will match a period. The double escape is needed, because Java recognizes Regexes as normal strings. This means you have to escape the backslash
  - `[0-9]+` - This will match a numeric character 1 or more times
  - This is all wrapped in `()?` because it is optional to have a decimal place. If you were to try `-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+` instead, it would not recognize a single integer. It would see the negative and period as optional, but since `+` returns 1 or more, it would require at least two integers.

An alternative would be

```
tempV.matches("-?([0-9]+\\.)?[0-9]+")
```

Comment: Note that this does miss a few numbers that `Double.parseDouble` would allow: `+2`, `1e2`, `.1`...

Comment: Note that this alternative is the worst pattern ever, since it needs to find all digits before failing with the dot when you enter an integer.

Answer (score 0):

> Because the String has to be converted to a double, alpha characters can't be allowed in the JTextField

What about `2.0E3`?

I would just use `Double.parseDouble`, and catch the `NumberFormatException`:

```
try {
    Double.parseDouble(inStr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // string doesn't represent a double
}
```

You could do it yourself with a regex, but there are various edge cases to consider: scientific notation (as shown above), a leading `+`, etc. It's certainly manageable, but why write code to accomplish something that's already done for you?

Comment: What would a leading + be?

Comment: A positive number. It's superfluous, but allowed by `parseDouble`.

Comment: Your suggestion is a valid one. However, I am exploring regex as well as java. It is more of a test project than a serious application. I will probably change to this method eventually.

Comment: In that case, in the future please include that sort of information in the original post. I read the question as trying to pragmatically find out whether a string can be parsed as a double; I didn't realize it was a regex exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You could cover all the bases with this possibly:
**edit** - ensure a digit somewhere, thanks @yshavit

`^(?=\D*\d)(?=[\d.-]+$)-?\d*\.?\d*$`

Could be extended to cover more as well:
**modified** - Simplified version, some assertions are not needed.

```
 # (?i)^(?=[^e]*\d)[+-]?\d*\.?\d*(?:e[+-]?\d+)?$
 # "(?i)^(?=[^e]*\\d)[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d*(?:e[+-]?\\d+)?$"


 (?i)                   # Case insensitive modifier
 ^                      # Beginning of string
 (?= [^e]* \d )         # Lookahead must be a digit (and before exponent)
 [+-]? \d* \.? \d*      # Consume correct numeric form 
 (?: e [+-]? \d+ )?     # Consume correct exponent form
 $                      # End of string
```

Comment: Is `.` a valid number?

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that catches a broad range of double input is:

```
^(?![+-]$|[-+]E|E|$|\.$)[+-]?\d*(\.?\d*)?(E-?\d+)?$
```

which matches edge cases of:

```
1
1.
.1
4E7
3.4E-5
+7.4
-5
```

See a [`live demo`](http://rubular.com/r/barLL8956F).

Because every term is optional, the negative look ahead is needed to catch degenerate cases that would otherwise match.

Note that this regex does not prevent over/under flow, eg `1E9999`, which is too large for double to represent.

Comment: Not sure, are `-.` or `+E2` valid numbers?